# Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Tags: software-installation

```
root@moonlight:~# apt-get install openssh-server
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: it is my big problam

Comment: Kinda reminds me of when I lose parity during a connection...  But anyways.... always amazes me how little people read... "is another process using it?"  hmmm... let me see, is something else trying to update the system at the same time?

Comment: See if synaptic is running?
try "ps -e | grep synaptic"

Answer (score 0):

One unfortunately cannot have two programs that use 'apt' running at the same time. That means you can't run software center & synaptic, or try to run either while doing apt-get something in the terminal. Trying to run two of these applications simultaneously will result in the error you posted. So close down synaptic and/or the software center, and it should be fixed.